# How can I delete ldap node and delete all the subtree node under it using Java?

Tags: java, ldap

[image]

Example, I want to delete `groupcode=SG` node and 2 subnode in it to but I get `javax.naming.ContextNotEmptyException`.

Here is my code:

```
    public boolean delete(String dn, DirContext context) {
    if ((dn == null || dn.isEmpty()) 
            || context == null) {
        LOG.error("#delete(?, ?): Some parameters is null or empty!");
        return false;
    }

    try {
        context.destroySubcontext(dn);
        return true;
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOG.error("#delete(?, ?): Error when trying to delete!", e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I do it? Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your LDAP server supports the [Tree Delete control](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-armijo-ldap-treedelete-02) and you can find a Java implementation of it, you're done: just set the context's request controls to include an instance of that control before executing the delete. It's not a common operation, and OpenLDAP for example doesn't support it.

Otherwise you will have to list each subcontext and delete the leaves recursively.